# \documentclass{book} + natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using `\documentclass{book}` and trying to get the `natbib` package generate the bibliography.

I have a root file, say, `root.tex` and different chapters are included using `\include{}`.
I'm having problems in getting the bibliography to work.

I have the following commands in my root.tex file:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

Any suggestion/solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: To ask the perhaps stupid questions: do you have any `cite` commands in your text, and do you run `pdflatex` - `bibtex` - `pdflatex` - `pdflatex`?

Comment: Besides adding a MWE, as Joseph has suggested, please describe the problems that you are having.

Comment: Other stupid question : do you ask latex to print your bibliography? It seems that you are just telling it to build one, perhaps not to display it. On a side note, what is your point using natbib? I suggest you to use biblatex, which is, in my opinion, much more flexible and powerful.

Comment: @Martigan `\bibliography{mybib}` prints the bibliography of cited works.